# IOS9 Coredata icloud after mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification, running executefetchrequest does not returns the changes made in NsManageobject

Tags: core-data, icloud, ios9

We are using icloud coredata and listening for NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification notficiation and merging the changes using mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification. After the merge if we issue executefetchrequest deleted and inserted nsmanagedobjects are returned correctly but the updated nsmanagedobject returns old values only. It seems to that after merge we can see the inserted and deleted changes but updated record changes are returning old values only.

Any help would be appreciated

We are using https://github.com/lhunath/UbiquityStoreManager

Comment: What MergePolicy do you have?

Comment: I have the merge policy set as NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy